# footer is not going to the bottom, using relative, absolute, and inline block, dont wanna use float

Tags: html, css, css-position

my html and css:

```
<style>
#header{min-height:100px;max-height:100px; width:100%;border:2px inset gray;margin-bottom:10px;}
#container{position:relative; width:100%;border:2px inset gray; padding:2px;margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;}
#leftbar{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:inline-block; width:25%;border:2px inset gray;}
#maincontent{position:absolute; top:0; right:0; display:inline-block; width:73%;border:2px inset gray;}
#footer{background-color:yellow;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">header<br>some more content<br>some more content</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="leftbar">leftbar<br>some more content<br>some more content <br>some more content</div>
<div id="maincontent">main content <br>some more content <br>some more content <br>some more content <br>some more content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer </div>
</body>
```

Image:
http://postimg.org/image/xapaykx4r/
What seems to be the problem? I dont want to use float. When using relative and absolute, how to place div#footer under #container?
Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use float? `position: absolute;` takes the elements out of the flow so the position of `#footer` will not be effected by the other divs.

Comment: It seems to be because you have absolute positioned the left bar and maincontent. So they are just going to sit on top of the footer. Remove them and you will be fine use float or keep inline-block and use a work around to stop the margin on the,

Comment: Here is a demo of your layout working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5zg3x78/). So we float the 2 children and use clear fix after, need to clear the floats! And done.

Comment: i found the solution: i made #leftbar and #maincontent relative.
Changed code:#leftbar{position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; display:inline-block; width:25%;border:2px inset gray;vertical-align:top}
#maincontent{position:relative; top:0; right:0; display:inline-block; width:73%;border:2px inset gray;}

Comment: @papps If thats what you want to do then nice, you could just do it the easy and normal way (my example).

Comment: @Ruddy, thanks bro, i know float and clearfix will solve the problem. But i was experimenting with relative and absolute :)

Answer (score 0):

the only other option is give height to container equal to inner divs

```
#container{ height:400px;}
```

some thing like that